# How to select a cell when radio button is TRUE in excel

Tags: excel-2007

I have a radio button with YES/NO option.
What I require is that another cell gets activated/highlighted ONLY when radio button YES is clicked, and not when radio button No is clicked.
For example:

Column 1.......| Column 2...............| Column 3.......| Column 4.|

Have Laptop?| (radio_buton) YES.| Which Brand: |.................|

......................| (radio_buton) NO...|.......................|.................|

I have less reputation points , so couldn't paste image. But 've tried to imitate Excel sheet.(sorry, bear with me)

Refering to this image, I want that when i click on YES radio button , "Which Brand" field gets activated/highlighted asking for user input. However, if I click NO, then nothing happens.

I've tried searching for its solution at various sites, but in vain. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using:
On click of Yes :-

```
Sub OptionButton1_Click()
Cells(<row_num>, <column_num>).Select
End Sub
```

On Click of No :-
 Radio buttons can be linked to the cell on which they are created. Such a cell stores the value of the radio button clicked as 1 or 0. I used the same to derive my functionality.

```
If [C22].Value = 1 
        [I22].Select  --Cell Number to Select
```

Answer (score 0):

If the radio button is a control element, create an [event handler](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx#BMadd_or_edit_a_command_button_%28control) in the sheet code module for it:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
  If OptionButton1.Value Then Me.Range("D1").Select
End Sub
```

If the radio button is a forms element, [assign a macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/assign-a-macro-to-a-control-on-a-worksheet-HA102749065.aspx) to it:

```
Public Sub OnYesRadioButtonClicked()
  If Me.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object.Value Then Me.Range("D1").Select
End Sub
```